# How to run traci.start for Sumo simulation

Tags: python, sumo, traffic-simulation

I have sumo 0.29 and traci it's supposed to be automatically implemented on this version.

I'm running the traci_tls tutorial and I want to get the execution time in real time and not in steps as the GUI gives.

I'm getting this error in CLI. when executing the GUI.

```
traci_tls ./runner16.py Could not connect to TraCI server at
localhost:51595 [Errno 111] Connection refused  Retrying in 1 seconds
Loading configuration... done.
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a severe error message, it is more like a warning. It is just saying that the first connection attempt failed probably because the GUI was slow to start. As the message says it will retry and I suppose the second attempt was successful (at least if there are no more messages below).